# How to move file in another server from one list file using while read line?

Tags: linux, shell, ssh

The goal is I want to monitor one directory from different server. For example the remote server is `user@host`.

I have `list.txt` that contents list of file that will be moved. And `list.txt` located in a remote server.

Currently I have this code.

```
ssh user@host cat /full-path/list.txt |
{
while read line;
do mv user@host:/full-path/$line user@host:/full-path/done/;
done;
}
```

When I run the code above, error exists. There's no such file or directory.

But when I log in to `user@host` and `cat` one file randomly from `list.txt`, the file exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `while` loop runs on the local server. You need to put the script in quotes so it's an argument to the `ssh` command.

... Or a here document, like this:

```
ssh user@host <<':'
    while read line; do
        mv /full-path/"$line" /full-path/done/
    done </full-path/list.txt
:
```

... or more succinctly

```
ssh user@host 'cd /full-path && xargs -a list.txt mv -t done'
```

Notice also the absence of a [useless `cat`](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html) and the local file name resolution (`mv` would have no idea about the SSH remote path syntax you were trying to use).

Comment: It would be very nice if what you tried could work, actually. With a suitable FUSE filesystem, I suppose it would work fine. But that is, by far, not yet a standard offering.